# SVM math question

Tags: machine-learning

I'm studying support vector machines and came across [this paper](http://www.tristanfletcher.co.uk/SVM%20Explained.pdf). The following equation doesn't make sense to me, especially the part with the 0 ∀i. Any help understanding the basics of SVMs?

yi * (xi * w + b) - 1 >= 0 ∀i

- xi - one input
- yi - the classification (+1 or -1)
- w and b - variables to find in order to "train up" the SVM (?)

Please forgive my ignorance on SVMs, a lot is still unclear to me and I'm trying to learn these bit by bit. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please make the question self-contained?  Also it would help if you can ask a more specific question than "it doesn't make sense to me".  What have you tried?  Have you tried working through some small examples (with just 2 or 3 points)?  Have you tried reading other tutorials or textbook explanations of SVM?

Comment: @D.W. I have studied this in many places and haven't been able to grasp the concept. I assume this question is totally understandable by those with a working knowledge of SVMs as it's kind of the basis for them. I don't understand what the upside down A means, or if it's getting multiplied by the 0. I'll update it to make more sense though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall$ means "for all", i.e., the equation

$$y_i (x_i w + b) - 1 \ge 0$$

is supposed to hold for every value of $i$.  To learn more about that, pick up a book on discrete mathematics and read its introduction to boolean logic and propositional logic.  (You might need a certain amount of background in mathematics to make sense of those equations, I'm afraid.)

Comment: So it's just saying that yi(xiw+b)−1 is always >= 0?

Comment: @JoshF Not _is_, but rather, _should be_. It's a constraint.